# Is there a way to count combination of columns in PostgreSQL?

Tags: sql, postgresql, group-by, count, subquery

I have a Postgres a table called MEMBER with 3 columns like this:

| id_musician | id_band | instrument |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | Guitar |
| 1 | 1 | Vocals |
| 2 | 3 | Vocals |
| 2 | 4 | Vocals |
| 2 | 4 | Guitar |
| 3 | 1 | Guitar |

I need to count on how many bands each member is/was member of. Is there a way to count this?

I tried the next code:

```
SELECT DISTINCT e.id_musician,count(id_band)
FROM MEMBER e
GROUP BY e.id_musician, e.instrument
ORDER BY e.id_musician;
```

But it gives me this result:

| id_musician | count |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 |
| 2 | 1 |
| 2 | 2 |
| 3 | 1 |

I want to get how many bands for each member for example

| id_musician | count |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 |
| 2 | 2 |
| 3 | 1 |

but with out the double row on musician 2

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `count(distinct id_band)`:

```
select id_musician, count(distinct id_band) from members group by id_musician;
```